# I create a query on a method that is an object and I don't know how how to make it return the object

Tags: hibernate, jpa, return

I have been searching and I haven't found an answer for my question.

I have the following code:

```java
public ScriptInfo findByForeignKey(int id) {
    Session currentSession = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
        
    Query<ScriptInfo> theQuery =
        currentSession.createQuery("Select *
        from SCRIPT_INF AND SPRINT
        where FK_ID_SPRINT=:idSprint
        AND FK_ID_SPRINT=SPRINT.ID_SPRINT");
        
    theQuery.setParameter("idSprint", id);
        
}
```

I don't know how to put the return so it returns the object `ScriptInfo` filtered.

Comment: Add a return statement on the object you created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Query` offers various methods to obtain the result of a query:

- `getResultList()`
- `getFirstResult()`
- `getSingleResult()`

The correct one depends on what exactly you expect and want to return.
Their respective behaviour is described in the [JavaDoc of `Query`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Query.html).
For them to properly work you need to provide information which class you expect the query to return, by adding it as an argument to `createQuery`

Your final code will look somewhat similar to this:

```java
public ScriptInfo findByForeignKey(int id) {
        
    Query<ScriptInfo> theQuery = entityManager.createQuery("select si from ScriptInfo si where si.sprint.id = :idSprint", ScriptInfo.class);
        
    theQuery.setParameter("idSprint", id);   

    return theQuery.getFirstResult();     
}
```

#### Note 1:

You use `createQuery` which expects an HQL or JPQL query, but what you pass in seems to be SQL.
This won't work.
Use either [`createSQLQuery()`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html#createSQLQuery(java.lang.String)) or use JPQL instead.
I recommend the later since I think you should only fall back to SQL when you can't express your query with JPQL.
Feel free to create a new question when you need assistance with the conversion.
Just make sure to include your domain model.

#### Note 2:

You don't need to `unwrap` the `Session` from the `EntityManager`.
All the functionality you use from the `Session` is also available in the `EntityManager`. Only `createSQLQuery` is named [`createNativeQuery`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#createNativeQuery-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class-).